# How do you change the allowscriptaccess in a browser programmatically?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, flash

Specify your operating system: Windows 7 (64 bit)  Video Capable Audio Capable and Local File I/O Enabled.
Specify your web browser and version: (Firefox 6.0.2 32bit)
Specify your Flash Player version win 10,3,183,5  Debug Player: NO
Give us a brief explanation of the problem, please include any information you feel is important
Question:  Where do I start?
The reason for this question: I am a developer of ASP.Net web applicaiton which has to meet HIPAA and CMS standards.
Currently, the web application runs on secure network and under https to a secure encrypted sql server, but open to public internet with secure login for specific members.

The other day, I was testing in VS2010 and had set it up to use Firefox as my default browser so I could view how it looks and operates in other browsers.  Of course in this local running, it run in http and is on the local network and secure.  However, I do enough research on open web that an x-shockwave swf got download and installed on my workstation and when I ran the test web application I had the following pop ups.  No code just the object id to let you know it was putting href links into my system (object id = _GPL_e6a00_swf).  The problem is that it was capturing words from the html page being displayed, sending them to textsrv, and then  putting a hyperlink on those words, like news.

I understand that this was occurring because it was working from my workstation (sameDomain).

I have written jscript to detect of flash player types and mimetypes browser addons.

Big Question, How do I write code, either behind (class or partial classs), or jscript or html5 or whatever to turn all flash player types parameter allowscriptaccess value="always" to "value="never" when the application runs?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you can set the allowscriptaccess param element on the flash objects using [jQuery SWFObject Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/) to value="never".

There are examples on this page of how to set the param:

[SWFObject Examples](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples)

```
<object data="test_flashvars.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_35357516" width="320" height="180">
    <param name="flashvars" value="name1=jQuery&amp;name2=SWFObject&amp;name3=Plugin">
    <param name="movie" value="test_flashvars.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="never">
</object>
```